# Security constraint is not working in App engine Standard java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints-v2

I'm using App Engine standard environment. I want to make all url to access only admin.

Here is my `web.xml` but this one is not working for me I test it on local development.

```xml
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>welcome</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <!-- OBJECTIFY -->
  <filter>
    <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ObjectifyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

  <!-- ENDPOINTS -->
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.EndpointsServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>services</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.example.test.API.Account
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <!-- Route API method requests to the backend. -->
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>EndpointsServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


    <!-- Security -->
    <security-role>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </security-role>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>admin</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>admin</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

I checked the documentation right here [Security and Authentication](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/config/webxml#Security_and_Authentication)

Can you please let me know why this one is not working for me. What I'm doing wrong ?

And second thing I want to ask is that If I protect all urls to access only admin can I still use cloud endpoint lib in Android can my app access endpoints or not without any login ?

I'm using `java8`

Comment: Do you see any errors, error logs or something? Please edit your question to include them.

Comment: I'm not seeing any error or something in log

Comment: App Engine does not support custom security roles (`<security-role>`), as mentioned in the very same document you linked. Try deleting it.

Comment: @Mangu If I remove `security-role` then it show error. `Security constraint: Can not resolve admin `

Comment: Did you literally just delete `<security-role>` and not its contents?  `<role-name>` must go away too.

Comment: Defiantly I'm remove it's content But there is another `<role-name>` under `<auth-constraint>` that is showing the error. Should I also need to remove this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using the [Enpoints Framework](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/), you must secure your API through the methods described in [the Endpoints Framework docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/java/authenticating-users).

The users will be calling the API proxy, not the endpoints on your app directly, so you must secure the API proxy endpoints.

You can see more a detailed explanation of how requests are handled when using the Endpoints Framework for GAE in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/frameworks-extensible-service-proxy#endpoints_frameworks).

Comment: But I also need to secure other urls for example push queue and cron jobs. How can I do that because above code is not working for me and there is no error

Comment: The document you mention is talking about how to authenticate user. I don't want to authorize user but what that no one can use it without admin. Whole application is to limit only one person which is admin